# oauth.io (oauth.js) with Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, oauth, github-api

I am trying to create a chrome extension. Need to auth with github.

I am currently using oauth.js for auth, using chrome extension boilerplate http://extensionizr.com/

When i try my code at localhost i can auth with no problem.

This is a my code for oauth:

```
OAuth.initialize('my key');
    OAuth.popup('github', {
        cache: true
    }, function(error, success) {
        console.log(error)
        that.auth_token = success.access_token;
    });
```

This is popup when i try to auth:
[image: popup]

This is console error:
[image: error]

This is Oauth.io domains:
[image]

This is rquest respose

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            (function() {
                "use strict";
            var msg="{\"status\":\"error\",\"message\":\"Origin \\\"chrome-extension://bfhbkhhimmcbjgofifofjgbjaojgbihj/\\\" does not match any registered domain/url on oauth.io\",\"state\":\"181DBPf5s84Q6s3rjMJHuiqSlPY\",\"provider\":\"github\"}";
            chrome.runtime.sendMessage("bfhbkhhimmcbjgofifofjgbjaojgbihj", {data:msg});
                window.close();
            })();
            </script>
        </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

Help me!

Comment: You are trying to call `chrome.sendMessage` from somewhere you're not supposed to, I think. In any case, the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: I just added rquest response which is posting with oauth.js. that using chrome.runtime.sendMessage .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

chrome-extension is not a domain, but a scheme. That's why it doesn't work.

See this answer here:
https://github.com/oauth-io/oauthd/issues/52

You need to use

```
"externally_connectable": {
    "matches": ["https://oauth.io/*"]
},
```

in the manifest, then `chrome.sendMessage` will be allowed to execute.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you very much. One question more, I am takin g this error message `Origin "chrome-extension://bfhbkhhimmcbjgofifofjgb…s not match any registered domain/url on oauth.io`
I know i should add domain to "oauth.io". But the extension id is not static right? It is different on every PC. How can i add it to oauth.io as a domain with regex? I tried chrome-extension://*/ and some other alternatives but didn't work.

Comment: @MustafaSamedKasal Extension id is static for a packaged/published extension. When you load an extension unpacked, it's dynamic (depends on the path among other things). To get a "final" id, upload to Chrome Web Store. You will be assigned a permanent id and can use it for your "release" builds.